# Calculating battery percentage after voltage drops

Tags: batteries, battery-operated, calibration

I would like to display a battery percentage based on the remaining charge in the battery. I do not know if there is a better way of doing it other than measuring the voltage across the batteries.

How do i accommodate the sudden voltage drop of loads that are switched on. For example assuming a single lipo battery with a 100% at 4.2 volts and a 0% at 3.5volts. With the logic circuits total resistance, the voltage will drop a little bit by lets say 0.05 volts, which is then read i can display the battery is at 94%. seems straight forward. Now if we add lets say a high power motor and upon turning it on (lets ignore the voltage drop over time) the battery voltage will drop by lets say 0.25 volts(due to added resistance) which mean that my microcontroller will read 3.95 volts or 64% (assuming linear voltage curve which is NEVER the case in batteries). But if we turned the motor back to off the voltage drop of the battery will go back to only 0.05 so i have to display 94% again.

I do not like displaying battery percentage that is going up and down, it will lead to confusion. Also i know that proper battery indicators do not go up and down, so i can conclude that there is something they have done to accommodate switched loads.

Comment: Measuring voltage is one of the least accurate ways of assessing the state of charge (SOC), particularly with Lithium cells.  ESR is slightly better, but coulomb counting is the only really accurate way.  Battery management ICs can help you with this.

Comment: I see, so i should ditch the resistors and opt for a coulomb counting IC. I will to to look for a basic one. Reading on a coulomb counting ic' so far i see it being good when you know the charge of the battery initialy, i do not see how it handles battery that are not fully charged. like if the battery is plugged in 50% charge left i should be able to display 50%(or something close) too

Comment: @Jakequin You would need to discharge the battery to a state that you are willing to define as "empty" and then charge it up to a state you are willing to define as "full" with the coloumb counting keep tracking of everything the entire time. That's why they are usually for system with a permanent battery or on a board mounted to the battery. It won't be able to immediately ascertain the charge of some random battery. Unlike a gas tank, obtaining battery state of charge is a pain.

Comment: @DKNguyen the circuit has no onboard charging, and is the battery is ment to be replacable. my application demands that when the battery is drained it can be replaced quickly and continue on. I now understand why videos phone battery manufacturing process always involves a last step of power cycling the battery. It would seem that coulomb counting does not fit the application what would be the next best thing?

Comment: @Jakequin I don't know if there is a solution. Better battery chemistries (like lithium-based chemistries) are characterized by a discharge curve where voltage remains relatively constant as the battery drains which is directly counterproductive for trying to measure voltage to determine state of charge. I didn't realize they power cycled smartphone batteries. I thought they assembled the battery materials so it starts with some state of charge and just program that initial point into the firmware.

Comment: @DKNguyen that is true lithium ion retains its nominal voltage as low as 20% of its charge. i guess what i can do now is just a battery low indicator until i find a better compromise

Comment: @Jakequin Yeah, Lithium voltages are much more uniquely recognizable when it is near empty. That might be the best solution. You could combine that with a coloumb counter that shows how much battery has been used since the battery was installed to let the human be able to judge things a bit.

Comment: Jake you need to understand the 3rd order non-linear model of a battery in order to make a better SoC sensor than the 1st order model of  reading a voltage concept. That includes double layer charge capacity, and SoC and temperature controlled ESR. After you understand then attempt to write specs without unavoidable memory effects inherent to all batteries.

Comment: If you dispute my assertion about hysteresis and memory. Have you every seen a battery that didn't restore voltage after a momentary pulsed load. It's just that memory aging is a bigger factor on re-use for some more than others and depends on time spent over/under charged using a 10/90% threshold. That means re-calibration depends on accuracy. This has already been done in lappies.

Comment: You could theoretically use a mercury coulommeter, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_coulometer . These were once used to determine operating time of engines, for example, but I don't actually suggest using *anything* containing Hg! See also https://www.elektormagazine.com/magazine/elektor-201707/40517/

Comment: Jake , I don't have much confidence in your ability to make a better SoC instrument until you learn how to understand and ask questions.  Take for example your lack of comments on my answer about overshoot measurements on scopes  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/476445/spikes-on-a-square-wave-of-a-oscilloscope-reading